# Verify and Catch 'Insert' Errors to Access DB

Tags: .net, database, ms-access, insert

I have a shipping program in VB.Net that writes to an Access DB when the shipment is proccessed.  Two insert statments occur during processing: The first insert statement records general package information.

```
    Private Function AddToShipmentDatabase()
    'Prevent null errors from database by changing empty fields to empty strings 
    If ShipmentInformation.CreditCardInfo = Nothing Then
        ShipmentInformation.CreditCardInfo = ""
    End If
    If ShipmentInformation.Tracking = Nothing Then
        ShipmentInformation.Tracking = ""
    End If
    If ShipmentInformation.TransactionId = Nothing Then
        ShipmentInformation.TransactionId = ""
    End If

    'Connect to local database and upload the information 
    'stored in the shipment information structure
    Dim strConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & My.Settings.DBFileLocation
    Dim objConnection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(strConnectionString)
    Dim objCommand As New OleDbCommand
    objCommand.Connection = objConnection
    objCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [MailLog] ([CustomerId], [ShipDate], [CustomerName], [Service], [Tracking], [Address], [RxCount], [Charge], [CreditCardInfo], [TransactionId]) VALUES(@CustomerId, @ShipDate, @CustomerName, @Service, @Tracking, @Address, @RxCount, @Charge, @CreditCardInfo, @TransactionId)"
    objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerId", ShipmentInformation.CustomerId)
    objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ShipDate", ShipmentInformation.ShipDate)
    objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerName", ShipmentInformation.CustomerName)
    objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Service", ShipmentInformation.Service)
    objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tracking", ShipmentInformation.Tracking)
    objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", ShipmentInformation.Address)
    objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RxCount", ShipmentInformation.RxCount)
    objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Charge", ShipmentInformation.Charge)
    objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreditCardInfo", ShipmentInformation.CreditCardInfo)
    objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TransactionId", ShipmentInformation.TransactionId)

    'Connect to database and add record
    Dim intRecord As Integer = Nothing
    objConnection.Open()
    objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Do Until intRecord <> Nothing
        objCommand.CommandText = "SELECT @@IDENTITY"
        intRecord = objCommand.ExecuteScalar()
        objConnection.Close()
    Loop
    Return intRecord
End Function
```

The second 'Insert' is a detailed listing from a datagrid of the package contents.  The first returns a record id that is used in the second listing to match shipment details to shipments

```
    Private Sub LogPackage(ByVal RecordId As Integer)

    'Loop through the records in the log and add to database
    For i As Integer = 0 To (dgLog.Rows.Count - 1)
        Dim strValues(4) As String
        'Id
        strValues(0) = RecordId
        'RxNumber
        strValues(1) = dgLog.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value.ToString
        'DrugName
        strValues(2) = dgLog.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value.ToString
        'Quantity
        strValues(3) = dgLog.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value.ToString
        'Charge
        strValues(4) = dgLog.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value.ToString

        'Connect to local database and upload the information 
        'stored in the log datagrid
        Dim strConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & My.Settings.DBFileLocation
        Dim objConnection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(strConnectionString)
        Dim objCommand As New OleDbCommand
        objCommand.Connection = objConnection
        objCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [ShipmentDetails] ([MailLogId], [RxNumber], [DrugName], [Quantity], [Charge]) VALUES(@MailLogId, @RxNumber, @DrugName, @Quantity, @Charge)"
        objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MailLogId", strValues(0))
        objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RxNumber", strValues(1))
        objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DrugName", strValues(2))
        objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", strValues(3))
        objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Charge", strValues(4))

        'Connect to database and add record
        objConnection.Open()
        objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        objConnection.Close()
    Next
End Sub
```

My problem is that on occassion the package contents do not get written. More specifically one item, when the insert fails, is missing. If two items are shipped, only one is logged. Three shipped, two are logged. Etc... I would appreciate any help to figure this out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up adding a loop to the insert statement and setting the result of the execute non-query to an integer. Now the insert statement loops until the result of the insert  = 1

```
dim intRecord as integer = Nothing
Do Until intRecord = 1
//CODE
//CODE
//CODE
intRecord = objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
Loop
```

So far it seems to work. Thanks!